# Can I populate the 'in' variable using a list of values stored in one field

Tags: sql, where-clause

I hope I'm not trying to do something that is not possible. ..

In my DB, the query below works and gets the values I want.

```
select LabelID, Amount 
  from tCASpreadsData
 where LabelID in (3,4,5,7,9,10,11,12,16,17,18,19,21,22,23,24,28,29,30)
```

However, I don't want to build the list of LabelIDs manually each time.  I also don't have a way to logically select them.  So, I created a table with all the values listed in one field.

The query below finds the list I want in a field called SumA.

```
select SumA from tlCECLRatio where CATemplateID = 1 and LabelID = 148

(3,4,5,7,9,10,11,12,16,17,18,19,21,22,23,24,28,29,30)
```

However, when I combine the two queries, I get nothing.

```
SELECT LabelID, Amount 
  FROM tCASpreadsData 
 WHERE convert(nvarchar(255),LabelID) in 
       (Select SumA from tlCECLRatio where CATemplateID = 1 and LabelID = 148)
```

How can I use the value of SumA to create the 'in' list in my where clause?

Comment: Looks to me as long as SumA is a nvarchar(255) then the query should work.  That may be your problem.  We'll probably need to see the table structure to know for sure.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You have written a pretty good question. It can be enhance by specifying which DBMS you're using and by providing a bit more detail of the table structures in text format. I encourage you to take moment to take the [Stack Overflow
tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You can also read about asking a [good
question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The help pages are pretty good. Following the norms of the Stack Overflow community and keeping in mind that this meant to be a knowledge base will generally result in better, faster answers.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like below no need conversion

```
SELECT LabelID, Amount FROM tCASpreadsData where LabelID in
(
 Select SumA from tlCECLRatio where CATemplateID = 1 and LabelID = 148
)
```

Comment: When I run this I get the error "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '3,4,5,7,9,10,11,12,16,17,18,19,21,22,23,24,28,29,30' to data type int."  Which is why I did the convert to nvarchar.  Thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
select LabelID, Amount 
from tCASpreadsData 
where LabelID in ( 
    select SumA 
    from tlCECLRatio
    where CATemplateID = 1 and LabelID = 148
)
```

Comment: When I run this I get the error "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '3,4,5,7,9,10,11,12,16,17,18,19,21,22,23,24,28,29,30' to data type int." Which is why I did the convert to nvarchar. Thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 0):

From your OP, it seems like you have the freedom to define the interim table (tlCECLRatio) however you like. So, I would like to suggest that you define it without a varchar field and instead use all integer fields.  Here's how it would look with the values you have provided:

```
CATemplateID LabelID
           1       3
           1       4
           1       5
           1       7
           1       9
           1      10
           1      11
           1      12
           1      16
           1      17
           1      18
           1      19
           1      21
           1      22
           1      23
           1      24
           1      28
           1      29
           1      30
```

If you need other collections of labels, you would give them a new template ID. Each collection is therefore defined by the value of CATemplateID.

To query the values you want, it's a simple join.

```
select SD.LabelID, SD.Amount 
  from tCASpreadsData SD inner join tlCECLRatio CR
                         on SD.LabelID = CR.LabelID
 where CR.CATemplateID = 1
```

---

**Side Note:** *I have been taught that the interim table also needs its own row ID, so I would probably define it as CECLRatioValue(RatioValueID, CATemplateID, LabelID) where RatioValueID is a sequence (or autonumber) value. But, that might be overkill for a simple cross-reference table. Just pointing out what has been recommended to me as good database practice.*

Comment: Thanks.  I started playing with this late yesterday afternoon and it works!

Comment: Glad to have been of help! Feel free to [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it was useful to you. :-) Here's a [tip about answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) from the SO site.